# Unable to remove V1,V2 while reading a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file as follows -

```
Sr_No,Location_Coordinates,Location,Hospital_Name
1,11.6357989,Near Dollygunj Junction,Chakraborty Multi Speciality Hospital
2,11.8311681,Medical Board Office,Inhs Dhanvantri
3,11.8311681,Near,Maricar Hospital
4,11.6498468,Lamba Line,Pillar Health Centre
```

With Sr_No, etc, ..... being all the headers - but when i am doing read.csv it comes back with the values as -

```
v1,v2,v3,v4
Sr_No,Location Coordinates,Location,Hospital Name
1,11.6357989,Near Dollygunj Junction,Chakraborty Multi Speciality Hospital
2,11.8311681,Medical Board Office,Inhs Dhanvantri
3,11.8311681,Near,Maricar Hospital
4,11.6498468,Lamba Line,Pillar Health Centre
```

How to get rid of all the elements 'v1,v2,v3,v4', because when i am trying to call the data frame after reading the csv file

```
s <- read.csv("../hospitaldata.csv",header = FALSE, check.names = TRUE)
```

if i try to do 's$' it shows me the option of V1,V2,...

i need it to be like s$Sr_No,....

Any help is appreciated.

i tried using skip=1 but it did not help. I am using MacOs.

Comment: Try `header = TRUE` instead.

Comment: @JakeKaupp - Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff>' throws this error already tried.

Comment: That error is not reproduced here, so it must be further down in your CSV file. From the `<ff>`, it looks like the file is not entirely ASCII, whether it is corrupted or just has a different encoding.

Comment: Did you search on the cause of that error? If you can't fix it you can always set the names after the fact.

Comment: Is there error actually on the first row? If so, you can use `read.csv(..., skip=1, header=FALSE)` and then rename the columns as @JakeKaupp suggested.

Comment: @r2evans - seems like the data is not proper. header = true was throwing me ...<ff> error and seems to be somewhere there are escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this line:

```
s <- read.csv("../hospitaldata.csv",header = TRUE, check.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry, try header=TRUE. I just edited my code in my answer

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the data, i have tried using header=TRUE and it did not work then i resized my data and then tried again and it worked, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well due to Sys.getlocale being en_US.UTF-8 i have to read the data by including fileEncoding and setting it to "latin1" as follows -

```
s <- read.csv('/Users/.../../hospitaldata.csv', header = TRUE, 
          fileEncoding =  "latin1", as.is=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer :
s <- read.csv("../hospitaldata.csv",header = **TRUE**, check.names = TRUE)

Below also Works Sometimes, but may go wrong many times :

s <- read.csv("../hospitaldata.csv",header = **T**, check.names = TRUE)

(Even if you use T instead of TRUE, this may lead to spurious results)